# Java GC log Live Object size

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection

I saw few million logs in our log file which listed "Live object size". I dont see this as a log written by our application. I suspect this is written by enabling Java Garbage Collection flag.

I am not sure which of the GC flag would start logging this log. Below are the flags enabled

`/usr/java/bin/java -verbose:gc

-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xincgc -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime  -Xms256M -Xmx2235M -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch`

Logs:

0x000000077f200278: live object of size 5

0x000000077f2002a0: live object of size 4